# Rails - how to display value through associations in form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations, form-for

This is my view:

```
= form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.autocomplete_field @user.city.name, autocomplete_city_name_users_path
```

On the second line I am trying to display the association, but I am getting

```
undefined method `London' for #<User:0x00000129bb3030>
```

The associations:

**User** `belongs_to :city`

**City** `has_one :user`

The displayed result in the error message (London) is right, but why I am gettng that error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `f.autocomplete_field` should be the name of a method. The form builder will send this method to `@user` to get the correct value. Since the value you're interested in is not in user but in an object owned by user, you have a few options:

1. Add `city_name` and `city_name=` methods to your User class:

   ```
   # app/models/user.rb

   def city_name
     city && city.name
   end

   def city_name=(name)
     city.name = name   # You'll want to make sure the user has a city first
   end
   ```

   If you don't know how to make sure you have a city, you could create one lazily by changing your `city_name=` method to this:

   ```
   def city_name=(name)
     build_city unless city
     city.name = name
   end
   ```

   Then your form would look like this:

   ```
   = form_for(@user) do |f|
     = f.autocomplete_field :city_name, autocomplete_city_name_users_path
   ```
2. Or you could treat this as a [nested object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). Add this to User:

   ```
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :city
   ```

   And use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) in your form:

   ```
   = form_for(@user) do |f|
     = f.fields_for :city do |city_f|
       = city_f.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_city_name_users_path
   ```

Comment: I have one problem with, I used the first variant and added yet the input for `country`. The controller, model, just everything is totally the same as the **City**, but when I try to save some information into the `User` model, I get the error: **undefined method `name=' for nil:NilClass**. How could be possible to fix this problem? I tried search on google, but unfortunately didn't find any solution...

Comment: See if the `build_city` example that I added above helps. You need to make sure your user has a city object, if you're going that route.